# Crear boton para generar pdf desde android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola me gustaría conocer alguna forma o si alguien tiene algún proyecto de ejemplo o tutorial para poder generar un pdf con información desde Android studio. He buscado pero no encuentro ningún tutorial que me funcione.

Comment: Qué error tienes de lo que has implementado o por qué no funciona? Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en recomendaciones u opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que investigaste o trataste por favor, nuevamente te invitamos a leer [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar la librería PdfBox:
https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

Tiene un proyecto de ejemplo que te puede servir de mucha ayuda
Con algo así podrías hacer un PDF sencillo:

```
    public void createPdf(View v) {
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    PDPageContentStream contentStream;

    try {
        // Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
        contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        // Write Hello World in blue text
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
        contentStream.showText("Hello World");
        contentStream.endText();

        // Load in the images
        InputStream in = assetManager.open("falcon.jpg");
        InputStream alpha = assetManager.open("trans.png");

        // Draw a green rectangle
        contentStream.addRect(5, 500, 100, 100);
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0, 255, 125);
        contentStream.fill();

        // Draw the falcon base image
        PDImageXObject ximage = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(document, in);
        contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 20, 20);

        // Draw the red overlay image
        Bitmap alphaImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(alpha);
        PDImageXObject alphaXimage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, alphaImage);
        contentStream.drawImage(alphaXimage, 20, 20 );

        // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
        contentStream.close();

        // Save the final pdf document to a file
        String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Created.pdf";
        document.save(path);
        document.close();
        tv.setText("Successfully wrote PDF to " + path);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PdfBox-Android-Sample", "Exception thrown while creating PDF", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, ayudanos a responder preguntas creadas en base a [ask] para que estas sean de ayuda a la comunida, no ùnicamente a el que pregunta, saludos.